# Knockout observable field not updating on input value change

Tags: javascript, data-binding, knockout.js

I have noticed that I cannot get some of the Knockout live tutorials working or basic examples that should demonstrate the observable data binding.

Here is my code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html> 
<html lang="en">

<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
        <title>Testing</title>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="knockout.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            function TestViewModel() {
                this.Name = ko.observable("Testing");
            }

            $(function() {
                ko.applyBindings(new TestViewModel());
            });
        </script>
    </head>

    <body>
        <h1>Testing Knockout.js</h1>
        <div>
            <div>
                <span data-bind="text: Name"></span>
            </div>
            <div>
                <input type="text" data-bind="value: Name"></input>
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

So when I open this up in Google Chrome or Firefox I would expect the value of the span tag to change as I change the text in the input, however this is not the case. Can someone please explain why the above does not work? (This code was pretty much copied from the documentation on the website)

Thanks,
Alex.

Comment: Your code seems and works fine: http://jsfiddle.net/FHGvy/. What version of knockout and jquery are you using?

Answer (score 61, accepted):

As of KO version 3.2 (as [Salvador Dali answer's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25493176/872395) pointed out) you should use the [`textinput` binding](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/textinput-binding.html) for instant updates:

```
<input data-bind="textInput: userName" />
```

In you are using an earlier Knockout version and the `value` binding, then you should make the following changes:

By default knockout updates the value of the observables on the change event (e.g when the focus of the textbox is lost).

If you want instant update you need to specify the `valueUpdate` option where the possible events are: `keyup`, `keypress`, `afterkeydown` see more info in the [documentation](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/value-binding.html).

So change your `value` binding:

```
<input type="text" data-bind="value: Name, valueUpdate: 'afterkeydown'"></input>
```

Demo [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/FHGvy/1/).

Comment: Ah well I feel silly now, just assumed it would be an insta-update and that I did something wrong.

Comment: @Alex: you're not alone. I was also stunned by the lack of update when changing the value in the input field (and not unfocussing it). Is was mostly thanks to **[this really good video tutorial with Steve Sanderson](http://channel9.msdn.com/Events/MIX/MIX11/FRM08)** that I figured it out quick enough to not post the same question ;-)

Comment: use valueUpdate: 'input' to make it update on any action (paste, drag-drop, clear field, etc...)

Comment: `afterkeydown` doesn't work reliably on iOS 7, see https://github.com/knockout/knockout/issues/1118

Comment: Guys, read the below answer as well. `textInput` is the way to solve this today.

Comment: you saved my day. thx a lot. but textInput seem not working. any reason >?

Answer (score 20):

The accepted answer is correct, but in a new KO version 3.2 they added [textinput binding.](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/textinput-binding.html) So instead of `value` binding you can use `textInput`:

```
<input data-bind="textInput: userName" />
```

It does two important things:

- make immediate updates
- handles browser differences for cut, drag, autocomplete ...

Comment: Thank you very much for this note! Almost everywhere in my app I added valueUpdate for instant update, this new binding makes life easier.

Answer (score 1):

For those who wander in here (like me) wondering why it isn't working.  Be mindful of your extra '()' usage.  This got me in trouble with a nested observable like this:

Bad:

```
<input data-bind="textInput: subItem().userName()" />
```

Good:

```
<input data-bind="textInput: subItem().userName" />
```